# How to implement a << interface in C++?

Tags: c++, class, boost

I'm working on a tiny compiler, and I use `boost::variant<bool, ClassA> info`to store the information of each node.

`boost::variant` will automatically call the correct `<<` operator of a specific type when I call `std::cout<< node.info;`

However, since the built-in formatting function of `ostream` doesn't satisfy my requirement(print `#t` instead of `1` if `node.info==true` and print `"string"` instead of `string`), new types of `bool`/`string` should be introduced.

I want to implement a template class `Wrapper<T>`, which behaves **just like `T`**(because there are lots of old code) and provides the interface of `<<`.

At first, the following version was implemented:

```
template<typename T> class Wrapper : public T
{
    public:
        template<typename ... U> Wrapper(const U& ... a):T(a...) {}
        friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& o, const Wrapper<T>& w);
};
```

This version works well for `std::string`, but when T=bool, since built-in types cannot be inherited, an error will raise.

My current workaround is to use partial specialization:

```
template<typename T, bool ISCLASS= std::is_class<T>::value> class Wrapper;

template<typename T> class Wrapper<T, false>
{
    private:
        T inner;
    public:
        template<typename ... U> Wrapper(const U& ... a): inner(a...) {}
        //Wrap the operators (= + += ...)
        template<typename U> Wrapper<T> operator !() { Wrapper<T> res(*this); res.inner=!res.inner; return res; }
        operator T() const{ return inner; }
        friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& o, const Wrapper<T>& w);
};

template<typename T> class Wrapper<T, true> : public T
{
    public:
        template<typename ... U> Wrapper(const U& ... a):T(a...) {}
        friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& o, const Wrapper<T>& w);
};
```

Obviously it is not a perfect solution because I have to wrap every operators of `bool` or any other built-in types.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps I better make the follow-up regarding `boost::variant` another answer.

Firstly, learning from @MichaelAnderson, and considering the interoperability with `boost::variant`, I would like to improve the design of the wrapper. We add a constructor to enable type conversion for from the nucleus type to the wrapper type.

```
template <class T>
class MyFormatting;

template <class T>
MyFormatting<T> my_formatting(const T& n)
{
    return MyFormatting <T>{n};
}

// int

template <>
class MyFormatting<int>
{
private:
    const int& nucleus;

public:
    MyFormatting(const int& n) : nucleus(n) {}

    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const MyFormatting& w)
    {
        return os << "int:" << w.nucleus;
    }
};

// std::string

template <>
class MyFormatting<std::string>
{
private:
    const std::string& nucleus;

public:
    MyFormatting(const std::string& n) : nucleus(n) {}

    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const MyFormatting& w)
    {
        return os << "std::string:" << w.nucleus;
    }
};

// c-string

template <>
class MyFormatting<char*>
{
private:
    const char* nucleus;

public:
    MyFormatting(const char* n) : nucleus(n) {}

    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const MyFormatting& w)
    {
        return os << "c-string:" << w.nucleus;
    }
};


MyFormatting<char*> my_formatting(const char* n)
{
    return MyFormatting<char*>{n};
}

// std::vector

template <class T>
class MyFormatting<std::vector<T>>
{
private:
    const std::vector<T>& nucleus;

public:
    MyFormatting(const std::vector<T>& n) : nucleus(n) {}

    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const MyFormatting& w)
    {
        os << "std::vector:[";
        for (const auto& x : w.nucleus)
        {
            os << x << " ";
        }
        os << "]";
        return os;
    }
};
```

Next, let's use the wrapper with `boost::variant`. The constructor of the wrapper enables conversion between variant of nuclues types to variant of the wrappers.

```
boost::variant<int, std::string> var_int = 50;
boost::variant<int, std::string> var_str = "fifty";
boost::variant<MyFormatting<int>, MyFormatting<std::string>> var_fmt_int = var_int;
boost::variant<MyFormatting<int>, MyFormatting<std::string>> var_fmt_str = var_str;

std::cout << var_int << " " << var_str << std::endl;
std::cout << var_fmt_int << " " << var_fmt_str << std::endl;
```

But `boost::variant<MyFormatting<int>, MyFormatting<std::string>>` spells too long. We can make it shorter.

```
template <class... T>
using Variant_Formatting_t = boost::variant < MyFormatting<T>... > ;

std::cout << Variant_Formatting_t<int, std::string>{var_int} << " " << Variant_Formatting_t<int, std::string>{var_str} << std::endl;
```

Since `boost::variant` use macro-template metaprogramming to emulate variadic template instead of using C++11 variadic template, I cannot make it cleaner using type deduction. This is the furthest I can get to.

Comment: Great. Since I `#define TOKENTYPES int, std::string`, things could be simpler (?): `#define FMT(A__) Variant_Formatting_t<TOKENTYPES>{A__}`

Comment: There is a bug in this solution : If `std::string` in the above program is substituted by `bool` or any types which can be converted to `int`, then the call `Variant_Formatting_t<int, bool>{123}` will yield an `error: ambiguous member function of initilizer::initilize(void*, const bool&)`, because the declarations are `(void*, const Formatter<bool>&)` and `(void*, const Formatter<int>&)`, and both the two have the same priority in convertion from `const bool&`.

Comment: @ZhengLuo Well... that's too difficult for me. Maybe you can consider some non-wrapper solutions, like custom iomanip.

Answer (score 3):

Could we consider something simpler?

Create a simple wrapper, using reference or pointer.

```
template <class T>
struct MyFormattingWrapper
{
    const T& nucleus;
};
```

And then a factory function for it.

```
template <class T>
MyFormattingWrapper<T> my_formatting(const T& n)
{
    return MyFormattingWrapper<T>{ n };
}
```

And then, you can specialize the formatting for each type.

```
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& o, const MyFormattingWrapper<int>& w)
{
    return o << "int:" << w.nucleus;
}

std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& o, const MyFormattingWrapper<std::string>& w)
{
    return o << "std::string:" << w.nucleus;
}


int main()
{
    std::cout << my_formatting(123) << std::endl;
    std::cout << my_formatting(std::string{ "abc" }) << std::endl;
}
```

---

Update:

C-string may be a special case. But it is not difficult.

```
struct MyFormattingWrapper_c_string
{
    const char* const nucleus;
};

MyFormattingWrapper_c_string my_formatting(const char* n)
{
    return MyFormattingWrapper_c_string{ n };
}

MyFormattingWrapper_c_string my_formatting(char* n)
{
    return MyFormattingWrapper_c_string{ n };
}

std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& o, const MyFormattingWrapper_c_string& w)
{
    return o << "c-string:" << w.nucleus;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize I could wrap it only when it was printed.

Comment: However, `cout<< my_formatting( boost::variant<T1,T2,T3> () )` doesn't seem to  work, because `boost::variant` will resolve a correct `<<`  in `cout<<boost::variant<T1,T2>()` automaticly, but won't resolve a correct my_formatting, and that is just why I use the complicated technique above.

Answer (score 2):

Nicky C's answer is great, but has an issue with partial specialization of functions not being OK. This means you can't produce a version that works on general vectors like this:

```
template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& o, const  MyFormattingWrapper<std::vector<T>>& vec)
{
    o << "vec:[ "
    for(auto v : vec) {
       o<<my_formatting(v);
       o<<" ";
    }
    return o<<"]"
}
```

You can get around this by putting the core of the specialized output into the `MyFormattingWrapper` classes and having only one `operator<<`

```
// The default one
template <class T> struct MyFormattingWrapper {
    const T& nucleus;
    ostream& output(ostream & os) {
       return os<<nucleus;
    }
};

// Specialized for string
template <> struct MyFormattingWrapper<std::string> {
    const std::string& nucleus;
    ostream& output(ostream & os) {
       return os<<"string:"<<nucleus;
    }
};


// Specialized for vector
template <class T> struct MyFormattingWrapper<std::vector<T>> {
    const std::vector<T>& nucleus;
    ostream& output(ostream & os) {
       os<<"vec:[";
       for(auto & v: nucleus) {
         os<<my_formatting(v)<<" ";
       }
      return os<<"]";
    }
};

// Now there's just one of these, so partial template 
// specialization doesn't cause us any problems
template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const MyFormattingWrapper<T>& w) {
    return w.output(os);
}
```

Comment: Obviously, my answer is more an initial thought, and I'm glad to see improvements.